# How to get Tour Dates information from a band page through API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a web site for a friend's band and I want to pull information from their facebook band page. Specifically I am looking to get tour dates. I am a beginner with the facebook APIs, but I did read through all of the documentation and I couldn't find anything on the tour date information through the graph API. I can pull basic info from them, but I can't seem to figure out how to get tour dates. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tour Dates are provided by the Bandsintown Facebook app (ID: 123966167614127). As such, you need to use their API to access the dates.

Fortunately, Bandsintown.com does offer a nice API. Check it out at: http://www.bandsintown.com/api/requests

The above was just to obtain the dates as you see in the 'Tour Dates' link for most popular bands.

If the band uses Facebook events along with the app, you could just do a simple call to something like https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=coldplay%2Fevents

Answer (score 1):

If the band is using the Events functionality on Facebook you can use that to retrieve a list of all tour dates. Check the Events API page in the Facebook documentation:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

And look at their example of what this looks like here:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=331218348435